# JQuery Mobile Label on Loading screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile version 1.1.1

I have a loading image with as a splash screen.

I need to add a version label to it but I do now know if this is possible or not.

Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: When you say you have a loading image, do you mean on an iOS web app? Or what?

Comment: When it's a jquery mobile app which is going to be made native using phonegap

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish (so I apologize ahead of time), but if all you're wanting to do is add a version number to the loading image, why not just update your image with each version release?